# Turn off "builders" in MapStruct when using Immutables

Tags: mapstruct, immutables-library

How do I completely disable using "builders" in MapStruct?  I don't want to use them at all as they are causing all kinds of issues for me.

I created the service file under META-INF (I would prefer a way to assign it to the mapping builder= but I did not see any examples how to do it right in code).

It is still trying to use Immutables "builder" instance instance of the "ModifiableXXX" instance I want to map to.  I'd even take a way of forcing it to the modifiable type if that is available.

In another mapping, using an update the ModifiableXXX (with @AfterMapping and @MappingTarget) approach works.

My mapper looks like this right now:

```
@Mapper
public interface MongoProjectMapper
{
    ModifiableProject mapModel(MongoProject project);

    @AfterMapping
    ModifiableProject updateProject(MongoEntity e, @MappingTarget ModifiableProject p);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completely disabling builders is possible via the `NoOpBuilderProvider`. You need to create a `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.BuilderProvider` file in the `META-INF/services` directory with `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.NoOpBuilderProvider` as it’s content. This will completely disable the builders.

There is a feature request to make this more granular and disable it via `@BeanMapping` or on the mapper level. Have a look at [mapstruct/mapstruct#1661](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1661)

Comment: I don't know why this did not work form me. I use Lombok with mapstruct 1.3.0.Final in Spring boot. I added a regular folder under resources : /resources/META-INF/services, under which i added a regular file named org.mapstruct.ap.spi.BuilderProvider. Into the file I only wrote : org.mapstruct.ap.spi.NoOpBuilderProvider. mapstruct still uses the Lombok builder in the generated resources. I even added the mapstruct-processor dependency because IntelliJ couldn't find org.mapstruct.ap. But still nothing.

Comment: Does it work with your build system? Do you have the `annotationProcessorPaths` in your maven-compiler-plugin (if you are using maven)

Comment: yes I have annotationProcessorPaths set in the maven-compiler-plugin. In it i have 2 paths. One for mapstruct-processor and the other for lombok

Comment: Can you try and remove them and add the processor as a provided dependency. Look at [mapstruct/mapstruct#1713](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1713) that has a similar problem. The SPI is not picked up by the `maven-compiler-plugin` since it is not present on the annotation processor classpath

Comment: In my case I have a single module (so a single POM file). I can't understand the changes that I need to do for that. I couldn't adapt the proposed PR for a single module project

Comment: That's the point if you are using a single module you would need to get rid of the `annotationProcessorPaths` and use a provided dependency of the `mapstruct-processor` in your `dependencies`

Comment: I will try it monday I give you feedback

Comment: thank you it worked. But why I still need to provide a builder name in the child class (I have a parent class with lombok builder and child one with a Lombok builder) ? Normally if mapstruct does not use it, it should not generate the exception Builder() in child class cannot override Builder() in parent class. I'm I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry I am not following. Can you please create another question with more details or ask in the Gitter room?

Comment: will do it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 49):

From Mapstruct version 1.3.1.Final we can use annotation org.mapstruct.Builder#disableBuilder within: @BeanMapping, @Mapper or @MapperConfig

```
@Mapper(builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
public interface ProjectMapper
```

Have a look at [#mapping-with-builders](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-builders) and [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/Builder.html)

Answer (score 1):

version

*org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final*

have some different

you can see source code in
org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util  line 110

```
this.builderProvider = this.disableBuilder ?
  new NoOpBuilderProvider() :
  Services.get( BuilderProvider.class, defaultBuilderProvider );
```

So configuring spi
about `org.mapstruct.ap.spi.BuilderProvider file in the META-INF/services`
doesn't work anymore.

You must add processor compilerArgs in builde.gradle to make it choose 'NoOpBuilderProvider'

like this:

```
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs += [
    '-Amapstruct.disableBuilders=true'
  ]
}
```